# Eclipse RCP cmd prompt handler

Tags: cmd, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing and application whithin eclipse rcp framework (3.0). I would like to create an Eclipse RCP command inside of the run menu that sends shell commands to windows cmd prompt.

How can I trigger it with an event?

```java
public class RunCmd extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        // I need to get runtime exec
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Using Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder are just the same as normal Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for executing Windows Command prompt.
There are different methods available for checking process executed properly

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

        public static final String ID = "com.example.views.play";
        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

            String command = "adb shell input key 26";
            try
            {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```